# angular-ui-router share states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I have a few states set up like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('accounts', {
    url: "/accounts",
    templateUrl: 'tpl/accounts/index.html',
}).state('accounts.view', {
    url: "/{accountNumber:[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3,7}}",
    views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: 'tpl/accounts/view.html',
            controller: 'AccountController',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        account: ['$stateParams', 'AccountService', function ($stateParams, accountService) {
            return accountService.get($stateParams.accountNumber);
        }]
    }
}).state('accounts.create', {
    url: '/create',
    views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: 'tpl/accounts/save.html',
            controller: 'AccountSaveController',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }
    },
    params: {
        account: null
    },
    resolve: {
        account: ['$stateParams', 'AccountProvider', function ($stateParams, provider) {
            return $stateParams.account || provider.newAccount();
        }]
    }
}).state('accounts.view.edit', {
    url: '/edit',
    views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: 'tpl/accounts/save.html',
            controller: 'AccountSaveController',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }
    }
})
```

and it all works fine.
Now I have the need to create some child states for both **create** and **edit**. They will use the same view and controllers, but I was wondering if I can use the same state.
For example, I will be setting up an address state which will look something like this:

```
.state('accounts.view.edit.address', {
    url: '/address',
    views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: 'tpl/accounts/save/address.html',
            controller: 'AccountAddressSaveController',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }
    }
})
```

and I will set another up for the **create** state like this:

```
.state('accounts.create.address', {
    url: '/address',
    views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: 'tpl/accounts/save/address.html',
            controller: 'AccountAddressSaveController',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }
    }
})
```

It isn't an issue to do this for one child state, but there are 4 others and I just thought i would ask if there is a way to share the states, like perhaps:

```
.state(['accounts.create.address','accounts.view.edit.address'], {
    url: '/address',
    views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: 'tpl/accounts/save/address.html',
            controller: 'AccountAddressSaveController',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may put your state config in a variable

```
var sharedState = {
    url: '/address',
    views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: 'tpl/accounts/save/address.html',
            controller: 'AccountAddressSaveController',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }
    }
}
```

and then simply do,

```
.state('accounts.create.address', sharedState)
.state('accounts.view.edit.address', sharedState)
```

Comment: I would make a shallow copy for each one using `angular.extend({}, sharedState)` or `Object.assign({}, sharedState)`